# Button Hover Sound using HTML5 Audio

Tags: html, html5-audio

Is it possible to use HTML5 to make a sound when a user hovers over one of my list item buttons? I'd like to play a very short click/chirp sound one time when a user hovers over a navigation button. I realize it won't be compatible on every browser or device and that's OK as long as it degrades gracefully. Would it be better to use Flash for this for some reason?

**Edit**
Also, if it's possible to do this I'd be interested in some sample code, including the javascript (if javascript is needed). I'm OK with HTML but not too handy with Javascript.

Comment: I would like to mention that this is a **really** bad idea from a usability perspective.  I get super super annoyed just from the stupid 'clicks' IE makes everytime I follow a link when testing IE functionality.  I can't imagine I would stay on your site for long if little beeps started chirping out as I moved my mouse around.  Bad idea!

Comment: nzifnab - very much agree even though I posted the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’ve not done anything like this, but it should be possible. E.g.

```
<audio id="myaudio" src="myaudio.mp3"></audio>

<button onmouseover="document.getElementById('myaudio').play()">Hover me</button>
```

I’m not familiar with Flash, so I’m not sure if you can use JavaScript to get a Flash file to play.

Comment: Flash can interact with javascript and vice versa - but for this it's not really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old answer, nowdays you can just use HTML5 really.

---

I'd not recommend a sound on a hover. Users can get annoyed very easily (I would).

In any case, here's how, and ***it doesn't need HTML5***:

#### 1) Have a simple javascript to play the sound

```
<script>
    function EvalSound(soundobj) {
        var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
        try {
            thissound.Play(); //Quicktime, Windows Media Player, etc.
        }
        catch (e) {
            thissound.DoPlay(); //Real Player
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### 2) Make an invisible embed with the sound

```
<embed src="mysound.wav" 
       autostart=false 
       width=0 
       height=0 
       id="mySound" 
       enablejavascript="true" />
```

#### 3) Make it play on hover

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li onHover="EvalSound('mySound')">Foo</li>
    <li onHover="EvalSound('mySound')">Bar</li>
</ul>
```

#### Alternatively, attach event with jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myList').hover(EvalSound('mySound'));
    });
</script>
```

**Edited** because realplayer uses `DoPlay()` instead of `Play()`.

Comment: "it doesn't need HTML5" - but it does, presumably, need QuickTime, Windows Media Player, or Real Player.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yeah, this was in '11 when IE6/7/8 was more of an annoyance. Today I'd also recommend HTML5 for audio needs, and some fallback that works fine in IE8. Also, I believe Windows and Mac at least are covered with QuickTime and Windows Media Player.